# What's the best strategy for tracking events using Google Analytics?

Tags: user-research, quantitative-analysis, google-analytics

We have a web-based enterprise analytics application, with many potential user interactions spread across many different reports. Thus we have potentially hundreds of trackable events.

We are reviewing a couple of different options for our Google Analytics events tracking.

**Option A is to track "everything"** -- mainly all potential user clicks, e.g. clicking on a data point in a trend chart, clicking on a filter toggle, identifying the option selected from a filter list, etc.

The engineers would implement this systematically, and we would have an agreed naming convention, whereby the event category, name and label would identify, say, the report page name, event type and user's selection respectively.

**Option B is to first identify a list of events that we want to track**, say a top 10 list of what might we would agree are the most important metrics , and ask the engineers to track only those things. We could increase this list over time, but this would require queueing the request with the engineers.

We have already identified pros and cons to both approaches but, from a UX research point of view, **which option is preferable**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is make a list of events which has to be tracked.
And Also track both starting point and end point of a action.
example:If there is CTA then this click in one event.
On next screen there is a pop-up and it has two events example: Cancel and main CTA.
By tracking end level events you can actually see how many events are happening and the routes that user is preferring and also you can check if you misinterpreting anything .
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Harshith but the question becomes how you define events which 'have to be tracked'? In theory, it's useful to have information on all the events, which we can do with Option A.

Comment: Ok. Firstly sort your use cases. Then sort your conversion points then see if you doing something new that user has not experienced till date say it as new feature. List all of them and start building a hierarchy. To start with start with first level main interactions then go deeper... But cover on broader way